# What arguments can I use when defining a service?

Tags: 8

Looking at [system.services.yaml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!system.services.yml/8), I noticed that some of the services arguments are strings starting with @. They seem to contain a reference to another defined service.

```
system.manager:
class: Drupal\system\SystemManager
arguments: ['@module_handler', '@database', '@entity.manager']
```

Are those @-arguments only references to other services? Are there any other type of arguments I can use when defining a new service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the `@` arguments are references to services. From Symfony's [Introduction to Parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html):

> You can of course also reference services, which looks a bit different in each format. You can configure the behavior if the referenced service does not exist. By default, an exception is thrown when a non-existent service is referenced.
>
> #### Yaml
>
> Start the string with @ or @? to reference a service in Yaml.
>
> - @mailer references the mailer service. If the service does not exists, an exception will be thrown;
> - @?mailer references the mailer service. If the service does not exists, it will be ignored;

You can also use `%`-wrapped parameters which are slightly different; they can be used to refer parameters or get access to special `SYMFONY__` prefixed server environment vars. (See [How to Set External Parameters in the Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html).)